# FLASK: form validation error

Tags: html, forms, flask, ldap

I'm creating a flask website with a user login page via LDAP login manager.
the LDAP connection is no problem but for some reason Flask won't let me validate my form. I keep getting an error. and I can keep my head around it.  I hope you guys can help me out.

My code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, make_response, request
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, login_required,logout_user, current_user
from flask_ldap3_login.forms import LDAPLoginForm
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager, AuthenticationResponseStatus
import wtforms
from dbClass import User, Module, Category, SavingType, Status, ProjectOverview, Idea

#init app

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://///'path'/database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
Bootstrap(app)

#Ldap connection
class Ldap(LoginManager):
# Setup LDAP Configuration Variables. Change these to your own settings.
# All configuration directives can be found in the documentation.


app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'host'   # Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'dc=,dc='    # Base DN of your directory
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = 'ou=users'   # Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=groups'   # Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn' # The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'sAMAccountName'  # The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with.
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = '????'    # The Username to bind to LDAP with
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = '?????'   # The Password to bind to LDAP with

ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class LDAPLoginForm(FlaskForm):


username = wtforms.StringField('Username', validators=[InputRequired()])
password = wtforms.PasswordField('Password', validators=[InputRequired()])
submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Submit')
remember_me = wtforms.BooleanField('Remember Me', default=True)

def validate_ldap(self):

    ldap_mgr = app.ldap3_login_manager
    username = self.username.data
    password = self.password.data

    result = ldap_mgr.authenticate(username, password)

    if result.status == AuthenticationResponseStatus.success:
        self.user = ldap_mgr._save_user(
            result.user_dn,
            result.user_id,
            result.user_info,
            result.user_groups
        )
        return True

    else:
        self.user = None
        self.username.errors.append('Invalid Username/Password.')
        self.password.errors.append('Invalid Username/Password.')
        return False


@app.route('/')
def index():
return redirect('login', code=302)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
frm = LDAPLoginForm()
if frm. validate_on_submit():
    login_user(frm.user, remember=True)
    return render_template('base.html',form=frm)

if not current_user or current_user.is_anonymous:
    return render_template('login.html')
```

My HTML template:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Opportunity 2.0
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('.static', filename='css/signin.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<html style="background-image:url(&quot;static/img/adult-audience-band-553586.jpg&quot;);background-color:rgb(80,90,102);">
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-inline-block registration-form"     style="margin:9px;padding:25px;"><img  src="static/img/BARCO_rgb_primarylogo_white.png" style="width:150px;margin:14px;padding:-13px;">
        <form method="post" , action="/login" style="margin:12px;width:586px;">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
            {{ frm.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        {{ frrm.username.label }}<br>
        {{ frm.username(size=32) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ frm.password.label }}<br>
        {{ frm.password(size=32) }}

</p>
    <p>{{ frm.remember_me() }} {{ frm.remember_me.label }}</p>
    <p>{{ frm.submit() }}</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block create-account"  type="submit"
                        style="background-color:rgb(240,0,0);width:174px;font- size:16px;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

The error I get is "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined"
I tried everything i could think of

EDIT: Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File      "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/app.py", line 90,   in login
  return render_template('login.html')
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
  File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/templates/login.html", line 2, in top-level template code
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% block doc -%}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 4, in block "doc"
{%- block html %}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 20, in block "html"
{% block body -%}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html", line 23, in block "body"
{% block content -%}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/templates/login.html", line 20, in block "content"
{{ frm.hidden_tag() }}
 File "/Users/wouterlefebvre/PycharmProjects/OpportunityApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'frm' is undefined
```

thx in advance

Comment: You pass the form to your template as `form`-variable, but inside template try to access it with `frm`-variable. A typo?

Comment: No typo :) even if i change it i still get the same error

Comment: Well, could you add full stack trace of your jinja error?

Comment: updated with the error @Fian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling Jinja that the variable it should be accessing is called `form`. Even though you the variable you are passing it is called `frm` Jinja will see it as `form` because of this line.

```
return render_template('base.html',form=frm)
```

Therefore your template needs to look like this

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}
Opportunity 2.0
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('.static', filename='css/signin.css') }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<html style="background-image:url(&quot;static/img/adult-audience-band-553586.jpg&quot;);background-color:rgb(80,90,102);">
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-inline-block registration-form"     style="margin:9px;padding:25px;"><img  src="static/img/BARCO_rgb_primarylogo_white.png" style="width:150px;margin:14px;padding:-13px;">
        <form method="post" , action="/login" style="margin:12px;width:586px;">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        {{ form.username.label }}<br>
        {{ form.username(size=32) }}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.password.label }}<br>
        {{ form.password(size=32) }}

</p>
    <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ frm.remember_me.label }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block create-account"  type="submit"
                        style="background-color:rgb(240,0,0);width:174px;font- size:16px;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

If that still doesn't work try passing the form variable to your login render template instead. I'm not sure if they're passed downwards through templates

```
if not current_user or current_user.is_anonymous:
    return render_template('login.html', form=frm)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer this does solve the error of form is not defined but now i don't see my login page and flask goes directly to base without any credentials given. any idea why that is ?